# How to connect flexible tube to copper pipe

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, leak, faucet

Underneath the kitchen sink, the faucet assembly has a copper tube that used to connect to a flexible pipe. The two have become separated as shown below:
[image: left: assembled faucet; center: faucet lifted up to show missing connection; right: flexible connector]

I have tried pushing the connector back onto the copper tube and it leaks only slowly.  How do I connect them together so that they don't leak at all?

FWIW, the brand is Price Pfister.

Comment: These may help: http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/ex-526-01 http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/25676-0500          Looking at these, and comparing to your photos, it looks like you may be missing a part that clamps the connector to the pipe. Good luck.

Comment: @getterdun Wow! That was very helpful.  I took the PDF printout and my photos to home depot where they said my photos showed a [sharkbite-type](http://www.sharkbiteplumbing.com/) fitting and hence, despite the diagram, no missing part.  Whatever the case really is, you have given me a great start.  Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, these links may help:

- [Exploded Parts Diagram](http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/ex-526-01)
- [User Manual](http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/25676-0500)

Looking at these, and comparing to your photos, it looks like you may be missing a part that clamps the connector to the pipe. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more information that I learned while doing the repairs which may be useful to anyone in a similar situation:

- Price Pfister has a [lifetime warranty](http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/support/warranty.aspx) (for noncommercial use by the original purchaser).   We called Price Pfister and they sent replacement parts for a nominal ($7) shipping fee.
- The above fitting failed because of a crack in the gray plastic insert.  (The gray plastic insert is visible in the right-hand photo above but the crack is not visible.)
- The fitting shown above (right) connects directly to the copper tube (center photo).
- In preparation for re-installation, to assure a good seal, one should clean the copper tube using a fine sandpaper.
- To reinstall, push the metal fitting up over the copper tube as far as it will go with hand pressure.  Then lightly pull back in the opposite direction so that the plastic insert and the metal part separate slightly.  This is the locked position.
- If needed, it is easy to remove the fitting again.  Just push up on the metal fitting as if to install and then push down on the plastic insert.  It will slide right off the copper the tube.